# Почему при использовании strcpy_s со строкой и указателем программа аварийно завершается?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

Почему при использовании strcpy_s(str, ps1) программа аварийно завершается? Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char str[] = { 'H', 'i', '\0' };
    char str2[] = "Hello!";
    char *ps1;
    ps1 = str2;
    strcpy_s(str, ps1);
    cout << "str = " << str << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для использования функции `strcpy_s` требуется включение заголовка `<cstring>`.

Согласно спецификации функции `strcpy_s` она вызывает *обработчик нештатной ситуации* когда принимающий буфер имеет недостаточный размер. Именно этот обработчик нештатной ситуации и есть ваше "аварийно завершается".

P.S. Почему вы пользуетесь в своем коде функцией `strcpy_s`, если не знаете как она себя ведет? Каким образом эта функция попала в ваш код?

Comment: Ааа... Всё я заметил! Я не обратил внимания на то, что str имеет размер меньше, чем массив str2, на который указывает... Как-то так...